# width 100% in mobile device

Tags: css, mobile

I'm adapting a site to mobile devices and setting html, body and main wrapper to 100% width, and blackberry with Opera mini and other devices show a width which is double than screen, as when they enter the page they appear "zoomed out", I guess this is more a device configuration thing than a CSS thing, but just in case:

Is there a method to get the real screen width in mobile devices? I try to avoid Javascript as getting width via JS would require a page reload and that's not nice, specially if browsing from a mobile, plus in my experience, JS is not very accurate with mobiles resolutions.

This is my CSS:

```
html, body {width: 100%; height: 100%;}
#wrapper{width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Getting width with JS should not require a reload. Have you tried this and it has not worked? I have never had any issues getting correct pixel width of screen using JS

Comment: I mean, it needs a reload in order to adjust main wrapper's width from server, in this case, in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There no need to define `width:100%` percent in `html, body & #wrapper`.
because they are by default auto size

Comment: Good point, although `width: 100%` is not the same as `width: auto`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, setting it to default works better than 100%, but it's still not 100%, at least on my Blackberry Opera Mini, it's maybe some 20% more than screen width